# Calculate number of jumps in Dijkstra's algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, numpy, graph-theory, dijkstra

What is the fastest way in numpy to calculate the number of jumps that dijkstra's algorithm uses? I have a 10000x10000 element connectivity matrix and use scipy.sparse.csgraph.dijkstra to calculate the filled distance matrix and a predecessor matrix. My naive solution is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.random import rand
from scipy.sparse.csgraph import dijkstra

def dijkway(dijkpredmat, i, j):
    """calculate the path between two nodes in a dijkstra matrix"""
    wayarr = []
    while (i != j) & (j >= 0):
        wayarr.append(j)
        j = dijkpredmat[i,j]
    return np.array(wayarr)

def jumpvec(pmat,node):
    """calculate number of jumps from one node to all others"""
    jumps = np.zeros(len(pmat))
    jumps[node] = -999
    while 1:
        try:
            rvec = np.nonzero(jumps==0)[0]
            r = rvec.min()
            dway = dijkway(pmat, node, r)
            jumps[dway] = np.arange(len(dway),0,-1)
        except ValueError:
            break
    return jumps

#Create a matrix
mat = (rand(500,500)*20)
mat[(rand(50000)*500).astype(int), (rand(50000)*500).astype(int)] = np.nan
dmat,pmat = dijkstra(mat,return_predecessors=True)

timeit jumpvec(pmat,300)
In [25]: 10 loops, best of 3: 51.5 ms per loop
```

~50msek/node is OK but expanding the distance matrix to 10000 nodes increases the time to ~2sek/node. jumpvec has to be executed 10000 times then as well...

Comment: For people who want to answer without looking at your python code, it might help to explain what you mean by computing the "number of jumps" used by Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Sure! Dijkstra's algorithm calculates the shortest distance between two nodes by using intermediate steps via other nodes. An example: The distance between A and C is 5, A and B is 2, and B and C is 2. It is then shorter to travel A->B->C instead of direct A->C. The number of jumps in the first case would be 2 and in the second 1.

Comment: @brorfred: I may be missing something, but it seems like the number of jumps can simply be solved as a special case of dijkstra with unweighted graph, which by the way, can be solved asymptotically faster with a breadth-first search (no need for revisiting old nodes like in dijkstra).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code can speedup 4x on my PC, it's faster because:

- use `ndarray.item()` to get values from array.
- use set object to save unprocessed index.
- don't create `numpy.arange()` in the while loop.

Python code:

```
def dijkway2(dijkpredmat, i, j):
    wayarr = []
    while (i != j) & (j >= 0):
        wayarr.append(j)
        j = dijkpredmat.item(i,j)
    return wayarr

def jumpvec2(pmat,node):
    jumps = np.zeros(len(pmat))
    jumps[node] = -999
    todo = set()
    for i in range(len(pmat)):
        if i != node:
            todo.add(i)

    indexs = np.arange(len(pmat), 0, -1)
    while todo:
        r = todo.pop()
        dway = dijkway2(pmat, node, r)
        jumps[dway] = indexs[-len(dway):]
        todo -= set(dway)
    return jumps
```

To speedup even more, you can use cython:

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
import cython

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef dijkway3(int[:, ::1] m, int i, int j):
    cdef list wayarr = []
    while (i != j) & (j >= 0):
        wayarr.append(j)
        j = m[i,j]
    return wayarr

@cython.wraparound(False)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
def jumpvec3(int[:, ::1] pmat, int node):
    cdef np.ndarray jumps
    cdef int[::1] jumps_buf
    cdef int i, j, r, n
    cdef list dway
    jumps = np.zeros(len(pmat), int)
    jumps_buf = jumps
    jumps[node] = -999

    for i in range(len(jumps)):
        if jumps_buf[i] != 0:
            continue
        r = i
        dway = dijkway3(pmat, node, r)
        n = len(dway)
        for j in range(n):
            jumps_buf[<int>dway[j]] = n - j
    return jumps
```

Here is my test, the cython version is 80x faster:

```
%timeit jumpvec3(pmat,1)
%timeit jumpvec2(pmat, 1)
%timeit jumpvec(pmat, 1)
```

output:

```
1000 loops, best of 3: 138 µs per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.81 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 10.8 ms per loop
```

Comment: Wow, the speedup by the first example is even more significant for larger matrices– An order of magnitude faster with 11000 nodes. Many thanks for the suggestions! I will have to spend some more time with python I think...

Answer (score 2):

Here's an (asymptotically optimal) O(n) algorithm.

Create a set of unvisited vertices, initially all but the source vertex. Initialize to 0 the jump vector entry for the source to itself. While the set is not empty, pop an element v. Using the predecessor matrix, collect v and each successive ancestor in a list until you reach one already visited. Iterate through the list in reverse order, setting the jump vector entry of each node w to the entry for its parent plus 1, then removing w from the set.